# Download Fails Immediately and gives this message (Failed - Server Problem) for Google Cloud Console using Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, server

I have no experience with this type of web development. So basically, I installed 2 wordpress sites on 2 separate projects with vm instances and when I try to export the backup file from WP Migrate, the file fails to download and gives only this mess (Failed - Server Problem). I have no idea what is going on. I didn't do anything and it doesn't do this for my other accounts either.

I've tried taking off some of the files from the export but that doesn't work. The file sizes are usually 500mb but i got it down to 100mb and it still wouldn't download. On my other google wordpress site I was able to download 1gb with no problem.

this is a google cloud platform issue, wordpress is doing everything right. I CAN'T DOWNLOAD THE EXPORTED FILE. It works on my other google console accounts just not this one and I don't understand why. I don't know what it would be called technically because I'm not a programmer.

Basically I'm in the process of migrating my sites from google because the admin area is too confusing and i can't fix anything when i really need to.

So can someone help me either figure out how to make wordpress download the migration file or tell me a way to transfer my sites without using wp migration and i can't download each file because i need the plugins, i don't have them anymore but they are still on this wordpress installation.

Comment: 1) Take the time to learn the technology/products that you using. 2) This is not a Google Cloud problem. You will experience these types of problems on any platform. 3) The problem is most likely your PHP configuration. Learn how to configure PHP and read the PHP logfiles so that you can locate and debug errors. 4) You have not provided any technical details that can help solve your problem. 5) I recommend moving this question to Stackoverflow's WordPress site: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, here's the thing. I have NO programming skill at all. I got a google account. found out how to install or deploy wordpress and use it. that is all. I don't know how to use this system without a cpanel of some sort. I had not idea it was even a php problem and i STILL don't know how to fix it.